# gerar imagem php sem salvar no disco e enviar anexo

Tags: php

Então, tenho um script que gera um boleto no formato de imagem (usando o imagegif()).

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu enviar esse boleto em anexo (uso phpmailer) sem ter que salvar a imagem em disco. Motivo? Evitar ficar usando disco.

Ou seja, há alguma magica para eu fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível usando a função `AddStringAttachment`.

No seu caso ficaria algo assim:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
// ....
ob_clean(); // limpa qualquer coisa no buffer de saída
ob_start();
imagegif($img); // gera a imagem (assumindo que já exista uma imagem em $img)
$gif = ob_get_clean(); // $gif agora contém a imagem gerada

$mail->AddStringAttachment($gif, 'boleto.gif'); // 'boleto.gif' é o nome do anexo que vai aparecer no e-mail
```

Comment: O problema disto é que precisa gerar o arquivo. Sei lá se é tão importante não gerar o arquivo mas é um requisito que ele colocou.

Comment: @bigown Isso não vai gerar nenhum arquivo. `imagegif()` vai imprimir a imagem no buffer de saída e o `ob_get_clean()` vai pegar diretamente de lá. Não vai nada pro sistema de arquivos.

Comment: imagecreatefromstring() também pode ser usado..

Comment: Então ele aceita um *stream* qualquer ao invés de um arquivo? Não sabia disto.

Comment: @bigown Isso mesmo.

Comment: Por enquanto deu certo. Vou ver se meu gerente aceita desse modo.

Comment: @daniel-omine se vc passar o segundo argumento em imagegif ele cria um arquivo.
No caso do imagecreatefromstring eu poderia usar o `$mail->addStringAttachment(imagecreatefromstring($img));` ?
**OBS:** dessa forma não foi, somente com o do @bigown

Comment: Bom pessoal, obrigado. Era isso mesmo!

Comment: consulte a documentação para ver o uso apropriado para o seu caso brow.